# Reflecting objects from a Multidiminsonal array java

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, reflection

Im trying to access objects from within a 2d-array using Reflection. I can grab the object holding the array such as Matrix[][] drawMatrix = getDrawMatrix(); using reflection.

Although I cannot scroll thru each object to get the information from it, such as drawMatrix[2][4].getID();

Here is my code from my Reflection class which I use to grab objects

```
public static Object getClassObject(ClassLoader clsLoader, String clazz, String field, Object instance){
    try {
        Class<?> clz = clsLoader.loadClass(clazz);
        Field _field = clz.getDeclaredField(field);
        _field.setAccessible(true);
        return _field.get(instance);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Currently ive tried the following, but to no avail.

```
 Object matrixObj =  Reflection.getClassObject(Client.classLoader, "renderCls", "drawMatrix", null);
            int sizeArray = Array.getLength(matrixObj);
            for(int i=0;i<sizeArray;i++){
                Object matrixRowI = Array.get(matrixObj, i);

                System.out.println("Matrix_Row_" + i + ": " + Array.getLength(matrixRI));
            }
```

I recieve nulls.

How can this be done? Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please include more code to explain.

Comment: Im not sure how it wasnt clear, I stated im using Reflection to try and grab objects from a 2d array of said objects, and asked how could it be done... But I included some sample code to please you.

Comment: You only need to use `Array.get` if you don't know the type of the array. You do know the type of the array, so if the class of `matrixObj` really is `Matrix[][]` you can just do `Matrix[][] array = (Matrix[][]) matrixObj;` and then access all the elements without any further reflection.

Comment: Than would I pass the matrixObj[2][5] into my Reflection.getClassObject(.., .., .. Object instance) param? Or could methods be called directly?

Comment: At what stage are you getting `null`?